# C++ boost forward declaration question

Tags: c++, boost, forward-declaration

I spend some time examining `boost::` libraries architecture and was interested with the following fact:

In some parts of the libraries a `yyy_fwd.hpp` idea is used pretty common (see `boost/detail` or `boost/flyweight` for examples).

These files obviously contain only forward declarations of some template-based classes and as far as I understand, could benefit in terms of compilation time.

***Could someone point out in what cases do they help and should I use the same idea when designing my own templates?***

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forward declarations are needed to reduce compile-time dependencies. For instance, when implementing Pimpl idiom.

One more case is that, for instance, `boost::pool`<sup>*</sup> depends on `windows.h` on Windows platform. When creating my interface I don't want to force the users of my class to include the system headers by using my interface.

---

<sup>*</sup>Ok, that's a bad example, because `boost/poolfwd.hpp` still includes `windows.h`, but I hope they'll fix this issue. And I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about boost, but these forward declarations also exist in the standard library. For example, `<iosfwd>` contains forward declarations for streams (which are templates, normally hidden behind typedefs).

You'd benefit from this header, when declaring an overloaded operator<<.

In your header:

```
#include <iosfwd>

class X { ... };

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const X& x);
```

Note that the header doesn't require the full definition of `ostream` (= `basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char> >`).

The rationale for the header is that those templates are cumbersome to forward declare yourself. For the above example, it would look something like:

```
namespace std {
    template <class CharT>
    class char_traits;

    template <class CharT, class CharTraits>
    class basic_ostream;

    typedef basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char> > ostream;
}
```